# How to update android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to run the app in the emulator after I made changes to the app, but the changes are not reflected in the app.

How do I reflect the changes to the app in the emulator?

Comment: Are you using instant run?

Comment: You are making changes to app and re-run app and they are not reflected in emulator ? Or you run with instant run ? Give more details

Comment: i don't use instant run, i made the changes and re-run the app but when i restart the emulator the changes is not on the app

Comment: When you run app on emulator, changes are there, but when you restart, they are lost ? And you see old app ? without that changes ?

Comment: no when i made the changes, i didn't get the changes just the same app with no changes